# Simplyfying FV with monthly payment calculation

Tags: excel-formula

- 7000
- 10008.54
- 13665.45
- 18110.44
- 23513.35
- 30080.62
- 38063.19
- 47766.04
- 59559.92
- 73895.45
- 91320.39
- 112500.50

In the above list, 7000 is stationary. From 10,008.54 to downwards, I have the following formula pulled down with $N$27 containing 1500 (does not change)

> =((((M27*1.05)*1.05)*1.05)*1.05)+$N$27

This essentially calculates 7000 compounded 4 times monthly with  1500 added at the end of period. In excel I was able to come up with this

> =FV(P32,P29,-N27)+(P31*POWER((1+P32),P29))

- P32 = .05
- P29 = 48
- N27 = 1500

First FV calculates the FV of 1500 end of 48 periods with interest rate of 5%

The second part simplifies the table above. However the results differ by huge margin.

Question being: How else can I show my list above in short simple formula. I want the beginning of the month value compounded 4 times/weekly the following month + a payment added at the end of the month for up to 1 year.

Any leads and your time is appreciated.

Comment: `=M27*1.05^4+$N$27` will get the same numbers

Comment: Thanks Scott but that would only give the 1st instance on the list which is 10008.54.

How can I get the final number in 1 formula though?

Comment: Yes to get the grand total is difficult with the 1500 added each month, I am sure there may be some mathematician out there that can do it. but it might be easier to just iterate the formula 12 times on another sheet or in some hidden cells and then refer to the last cell.  I have spent nearly 2 hours on this puzzle and it is beyond me.  The first part is easy `=C16*(1+$E$16)^(11*4)`.  It is dealing with the constant additive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put this out there.  This is a UDF that will do what you want.  I realize that you did not ask for a vba answer but just in case you are open to one:

```
Function FVSPECIAL(rate As Double, nper As Double, PV As Double, PMT As Double, PMTEvry As Double)

Dim i As Integer
Dim otpt As Double
otpt = PV
For i = 1 To CInt(nper / PMTEvry) - 1
    otpt = otpt * (1 + rate) ^ (PMTEvry) + PMT

Next i
FVSPECIAL = otpt
End Function
```

Add a module to the workbook and paste this into it.

[image]

Then call the function. To call it you would, using the cells from the question

```
=FVSPECIAL(P32,P29,M27,N27,4)
```

It basically is `FVSPECIAL(Rate,Nper,PV,PMT, # of NPer per payment)`

Comment: Hi,
I am open to the VBA option as well. However I am getting a #name error for using this (240% for 12 months compounded 4 times a month aka 5% compounded weekly for a year)

>=FVSPECIAL(240,12,7000,1500,4)

Comment: @Shanan Try just the values and see if it works `=FVSPECIAL(0.05,48,7000,1500,4)`

Comment: @Shanan glad I could help.